# Multinomial distribution pdf and fisher information matrix

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, multinomial-distribution, fisher-information

The question is from Robert Hogg et al's Introduction to Mathematical Statistics 6th Edition Page 347 Example 6.4.5. It says:

Consider a random trial which can result in one, and only one, of k outcomes or categories. Let $X_j$ be 1 or 0 depending on whether the $jth$ outcome occurs or does not, for $j = 1, . . . , k$. Suppose the probability
that outcome $j$ occurs is $p_j$; hence,$\sum_{j=1}^{k}p_j=1$.
Let $X = (X_1, . . . , X_{k−1})'$
and $p = (p_1, . . . , p_{k−1})'$  . The distribution of X is multinomial; see Section 3.1.
Recall that the pmf is given by

$f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{p})=(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}{p_{j}}^{x_j}){(1-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}p_j)}^{1-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}x_j}$

My question is for the last term why it is :${(1-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}p_j)}^{1-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}x_j}$ ? It think it should be ${(1-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}p_j)}^{\mathbf{n}-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}x_j}$.

Is it a typo? or just because it doesn't matter whether it is a "1" or "n" for fisher information matrix then the authors leave it as a "1" there.

Comment: This is a question you likely can answer yourself in a minute or two. Why not write down all three possibilities for $\mathbf{p}$ and $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{p})$ when $k=3$ (or even just the two possibilities for $k=2$) and compare them to what Hogg's formula says?

Comment: Thanks, I think how many trials were made were missing here. I still don't understand the formula.

Comment: When $k=2$ the sums become single values and the formula expands to $$f(x_1,p_1)=(p_1^{x_1})(1-p_1)^{\color{Red}{1}-x_1}.$$ You are asking whether $\color{Red}{1}$ in the second exponent should instead be $n$, which is $2$ in this case. By comparing to the PDF for a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) with parameters $(1,p_1)$ (which of course is what this is) you will immediately see which is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, when k=2, it is Bournelli, I can understand that, but when K=3, it confused me.  $f(x_1,x_2;p_1,p_2)=p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}[1-(p_{1}+p_2)]^{1-(x_1+x_2)}$ Why it is still be "1" and why $X_j$ has to be 0 and 1 here? Sorry cannot edit my own comments.

Comment: Thanks whuber, I think the pdf is for one trial (or one sample only) of the multinomail distribution. But usually the pdf is for n trials.

Comment: By definition you have quoted, $X_j$ records the outcome of a single trial only.

Comment: I think that you are right and it should be n instead of 1.